# Tor Address Migrate/Copying

Tags: onion-routing, address

*Hello, I want to move my v3 onion address to the new server. How can I do?
Thanks*

Answer (score 0):

Check in your current torrc file (/etc/tor/torrc on Linux OS) name of directory where your domain reside.
It will be after HiddenServiceDir (/var/lib/tor/... on Linux OS)

Copy that folder to a new server. Check owner (different for different OS) and permissions. Write it to your new torrc file or just copy it if you're moving to similar OS.

That's it.

Comment: I'm doing what you say, but onionsite gives a has notfound error

Comment: More information please. Your OS? Where you're moving it to? Do you have root access?